Nvidia installer wont work with compiler
I have ran the nvidia installer on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in multiple ways and I am stuck on the compiler. First I can run 'gcc -v' to check which version of the compiler is installed. I get this as a result:
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1-22.04) 

Next, so when i run the nvidia installer, I entered, CC=gcc-11.4.0 ./pathToInstaller and the log says this:
(Answer: Continue installation)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="gcc-11.4".
-> Performing CC check.
ERROR: The CC sanity check failed:

The C compiler 'gcc-11.4' does not appear to be able to
create object files.  Please make sure you have 
your Linux distribution's libc development package
installed and that 'gcc-11.4' is a valid C compiler
name.

I tried to run the nvidia installer with the compiler also set to 12.4 and got the same result.
As an addage somebody said to try to run this first: export cc=/usr/bin/gcc-11.4 and this is the result below:
Warning: Compiler version check failed:

The major and minor number of the compiler used to
compile the kernel:

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38

does not match the compiler used here:

cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR  PURPOSE.

Also i should mention i tried this command: sudo apt-get install build-essential and the result was:
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.


The 6.5 kernel needs the gcc-12 to compile Nvidia modules, but you don't need to do anything -- gcc-12 will be a dependency and will be brought in with the Nvidia module or kernel, gcc-12 will be found without changing the default gcc or you doing any variable setup. A couple of weeks in Jan, gcc-12 wasn't a dependency, and you had to manually install it yourself. All assumes you get the Nvida drivers from the standard Canonical repos. Which version of the driver are you using?

550.67 driver, but i got it from nvidia's website. If i get it from the repository instead will it still be the most up to date driver?

The standard repos have 545.29.06, but the graphics-drivers ppa has a 550 (not sure which).  I stick with the standard repos, unless I'm testing new stuff.  The Canonical drivers come with all the "glue" code to recompile the driver when kernel or driver gets updates, so you avoid the manual fix-ups necessary for drivers from any other source.

What a coincodence that ubfan1 just made that post. I came here in order to update that i just wound up getting it from the ppa repository. If you have any troubles with Nvidia graphics drivers see here: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/nvidia.html#ID1 What happened with the driver in question was i could install it but it and it completed with an libglvnd library error. Resulting in not being able to start x or gui in any manner.

What a coincidence that ubfan1 just made that post. I came here in order to update that i just wound up getting it from the ppa repository. If you have any troubles with Nvidia graphics drivers see here: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/nvidia.html#ID1 What happened with the driver in question was i could install it but it and it completed with an libglvnd library error. Resulting in not being able to start x or gui in any manner.The error was "unable to determine path to install teh libglvnd EGL vendor library config files. Check that you have pkg-config and libglvnd development libraries or specify path..."
